# How to display the data in the nested section in the tableview

Tags: ios

```
{
    "data":[
            {

            "mainquestion":"was the staff",
            "items":[

              {
              "button_type":"2",
              "question": "Gender",
              "options": ["Male","Female"]

              },
              {
              "button_type":"2",
              "question": "How old are you",
              "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 35","Age 36 to 50","Age 51 to 70","70 and above"]

             }
           ]
            }, {

            "mainquestion":"Please tell the feedback",
            "items":[

                     {
                     "button_type":"2",
                     "question": "Gender",
                     "options": ["Male","Female"]

                     },
                     {
                     "button_type":"2",
                     "question": "How old are you",
                     "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 35","Age 36 to 50","Age 51 to 70","70 and above"]

                     },
                     {
                     "button_type":"2",
                     "question": "How old are you",
                     "options": ["Under 18","Age 18 to 35","Age 36 to 50","Age 51 to 70","70 and above"]

                     }
                     ]
            }
            ]
   }
```

This is the data format from the api.I need to list the data in the grouped tableview.How to implement the nested sections in the tableview .

I need the output as this manner.

```
Output:-

    1.was the staff

    a.Gender
    i.Male
    j.Female

    b.How old are you
    i.Under 18
    j.Age 18 to 35

    2.Please tell the feedback

    a.Gender
    i.Male
    j.Female

    b.How old are you
    i.Under 18
    j.Age 18 to 35
```

This is the pattern how to list the data in the tableview in grouped.

Currently i have the code as this manner:-

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return questionViewModel.numberOfSections()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 100

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let identifier = "HeaderCell"

        var headercell: QuestionHeader! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionHeader

        if headercell == nil {

            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "QuestionHeader", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)                

            headercell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? QuestionHeader

        }
        headercell.setReviewData(reviews:questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection:section))
        headercell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return headercell    

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return questionViewModel.numberOfRowsIn(section: section)

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
        print(model.answerType)

        print(model.answerType?.rawValue)
        let c = model.answerType
        return c!.cellType().getHeight()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let model = questionViewModel.titleForHeaderInSection(atsection: indexPath.section)
        print(model.answerType)

        print(model.answerType?.rawValue)

        let c = model.answerType
        let cellClass = c?.cellType().getClass()
        print(cellClass)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: (cellClass?.cellReuseIdentifier())!, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell
        print(cell)

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        let optionModel = questionViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath)

        cell.setOptions(Options1: optionModel)

        return cell

    }
```

This is code currently i have done .Here the nested sections is not used .So how to implement the nested section in the tableview.

How to list the main question then in main question list the sub question.Then list the options from each subsections.How to implement in this manner?

Comment: Probably this will help you out -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783478/how-to-create-uitableview-with-multilevel-expandable-collapsible-rows <=> http://me.deepakbhati.com/2016/03/23/multilevel-uitableview/ <=> http://sugartin.info/2011/07/20/447/

Comment: @dahiya_boy i need in swift3

Comment: No one do code for you, you got idea, now do yourself. If you stuck somewhere then post your issue we will look into it.